# Tables: Centering multicolumn when using inter-column spacing

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I would like to center a `multicolumn` cell, usually done via `\multicolumn{2}{c}{...}`. However, when using extra inter-column spacing via `@{\hspace{...}}`, the centering includes this extra space and ends up being misaligned.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{15mm}}rr@{\hspace{15mm}}rr@{\hspace{15mm}}rr}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Front} & 
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Group 1} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Group 2} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Group 3}\\
    &
      Value 1.1 & Value 1.2 &
      Value 2.1 & Value 2.2 &
      Value 3.1 & Value 3.2 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Ok, great, thanks. I tried using italics, but it wasn't as clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the space in `\multicolumn` as needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{15mm}}rr@{\hspace{15mm}}rr@{\hspace{15mm}}rr}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Front} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c@{\hspace{15mm}}}{Group 1} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c@{\hspace{15mm}}}{Group 2} &
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Group 3}\\
    &
      Value 1.1 & Value 1.2 &
      Value 2.1 & Value 2.2 &
      Value 3.1 & Value 3.2 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the space in the `@{}` bound to the left or the right column? What about when I have `@{}` after the last or before the first column, where do I need to put it? I would appreciate a link to some kind of documentation about this issue.